Not able to send POST request , getting 401 unauthorised response in postman ,in springboot rest api , seems issue with CSRF
GET request is working fine , but POST request is getting denied in postman , even after adding admin username and password ,  getting 401 unauthorised error , and after tracing in logs, seems like the issue is with csrf .
Even though have written the code correctly , still not able to figure out what's wrong with it.
If anyone can help me , that will be great. Thanks
postman error
postman error
console error
console error
console error
package com.chinmay.couponService.security.config;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration 
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        
        http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET , "/couponapi/coupons/**")
                .hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN"));
                
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST , "/couponapi/coupons/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                );
        
        //http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers( "/couponapi/coupons/**"));
    http.csrf(csrf->csrf.disable());
        return http.build();
    }
    
}


@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;
        
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepo.findByEmail(username);
        
        if(user==null)
        {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found for email" + username);
        }
        
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail() , user.getPassword() , user.getRoles());
    }

}




@RestController
@RequestMapping("/couponapi")
public class CouponController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CouponRepo repo;
        
    @PostMapping("/coupons")
    public Coupon create(@RequestBody Coupon coupon)
    {
        return repo.save(coupon);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/coupons/{code}" )
    public Coupon getCoupon(@PathVariable("code") String code) {
        return repo.findByCode(code);
    }   
}

Edit - If I add @EnableWebSecurity on WebSecurityConfig class, still it doesn't work
and I get following in console
==========================
CONDITION EVALUATION DELTA
Positive matches:
None

Negative matches:
SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration:
Did not match:
- @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: springSecurityFilterChain; SearchStrategy: all) found beans named springSecurityFilterChain (OnBeanCondition)
Matched:
- @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity' (OnClassCondition)
Exclusions:
None

Unconditional classes:
None

Hi everyone , the issue is resolved ,  I just forgot to add @Bean on SecurityFilterChain method , it was my stupid mistake

@dur , Hi I found my stupid mistake , I missed out to add Bean annotation on SecurityFilterChain method.
